# SQL delete loop

Tags: sql, loops, count

I have a table of housing listings.  I would like to keep a maximum of 10 listings per city.
(Most cities have less than 10 listings).

When I do this query:

```
 select city, count(city) as cityCount from tREaltyTrac group by city
```

SQL returns:

```
Acampo  1
Acton   1
Adelanto    20
Agua Dulce  1
Aguanga 1
Akron   19
Albany  12
Albion  3
Alexandria  14
Algonac 1
Alhambra    5
```

So Adelanto, Akron, Albany, and Alexandria must be cut back to only 10 listings ordered by most recent datetime field called 'creation' (order by creation desc).

Can anyone think of a procedure that will cut the listings back as described?

Comment: Is there some criteria by which you want to order the culling of the cities?

Comment: I am keeping the top 10 ordered by creation desc (newest 10).

Comment: RDBMS flavor and version please...

Comment: Could you post the table definiton? Does it have a primary key?

Comment: What server are you using? What version?

Comment: don't loop for such a simple task! use the power of a database to work on sets of data, see my answer for a single SQL delete to make this work for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**DON'T LOOP!**

I prefer marking th rows with a status, but this will do as you want and delete them...

try this (sql server)

set up table

```
create table tREaltyTrac (city varchar(20),creation datetime)
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Acampo'      ,getdate()) --1
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Acton'       ,getdate()) --1
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Adelanto'    ,getdate()) --20
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Adelanto'    ,getdate()) --20
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Adelanto'    ,getdate()) --20
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Adelanto'    ,getdate()) --20
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Adelanto'    ,getdate()) --20
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Adelanto'    ,getdate()) --20
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Adelanto'    ,getdate()) --20
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Adelanto'    ,getdate()) --20
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Adelanto'    ,getdate()) --20
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Adelanto'    ,getdate()) --20
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Adelanto'    ,getdate()) --20
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Adelanto'    ,getdate()) --20
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Adelanto'    ,getdate()) --20
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Adelanto'    ,getdate()) --20
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Adelanto'    ,getdate()) --20
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Adelanto'    ,getdate()) --20
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Adelanto'    ,getdate()) --20
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Adelanto'    ,getdate()) --20
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Adelanto'    ,getdate()) --20
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Adelanto'    ,getdate()) --20
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Agua Dulce'  ,getdate()) --1
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Aguanga'     ,getdate()) --1
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Akron'       ,getdate()) --19
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Akron'       ,getdate()) --19
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Akron'       ,getdate()) --19
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Akron'       ,getdate()) --19
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Akron'       ,getdate()) --19
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Akron'       ,getdate()) --19
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Akron'       ,getdate()) --19
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Akron'       ,getdate()) --19
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Akron'       ,getdate()) --19
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Akron'       ,getdate()) --19
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Akron'       ,getdate()) --19
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Akron'       ,getdate()) --19
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Akron'       ,getdate()) --19
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Akron'       ,getdate()) --19
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Akron'       ,getdate()) --19
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Akron'       ,getdate()) --19
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Akron'       ,getdate()) --19
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Akron'       ,getdate()) --19
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Akron'       ,getdate()) --19
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Albany'      ,getdate()) --12
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Albany'      ,getdate()) --12
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Albany'      ,getdate()) --12
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Albany'      ,getdate()) --12
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Albany'      ,getdate()) --12
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Albany'      ,getdate()) --12
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Albany'      ,getdate()) --12
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Albany'      ,getdate()) --12
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Albany'      ,getdate()) --12
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Albany'      ,getdate()) --12
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Albany'      ,getdate()) --12
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Albany'      ,getdate()) --12
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Albion'      ,getdate()) --3
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Albion'      ,getdate()) --3
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Albion'      ,getdate()) --3
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Alexandria'  ,getdate()) --14
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Alexandria'  ,getdate()) --14
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Alexandria'  ,getdate()) --14
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Alexandria'  ,getdate()) --14
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Alexandria'  ,getdate()) --14
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Alexandria'  ,getdate()) --14
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Alexandria'  ,getdate()) --14
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Alexandria'  ,getdate()) --14
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Alexandria'  ,getdate()) --14
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Alexandria'  ,getdate()) --14
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Alexandria'  ,getdate()) --14
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Alexandria'  ,getdate()) --14
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Alexandria'  ,getdate()) --14
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Alexandria'  ,getdate()) --14
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Algonac'     ,getdate()) --1
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Alhambra'    ,getdate()) --5
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Alhambra'    ,getdate()) --5
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Alhambra'    ,getdate()) --5
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Alhambra'    ,getdate()) --5
waitfor delay '00:00:01'
insert into tREaltyTrac values ('Alhambra'    ,getdate()) --5
```

display table values

```
select city,count(*) from tREaltyTrac group by city
select * from tREaltyTrac
```

delete the rows you don't want

```
delete from tREaltyTrac
    from tREaltyTrac
        inner join (select
                        city,creation, row_number() over(partition by city order by city) AS RankValue
                        from tREaltyTrac
                   ) dt on tREaltyTrac.city=dt.city AND tREaltyTrac.creation=dt.creation
    where dt. RankValue>10
```

show the rows you have left

```
select * from tREaltyTrac
select city,count(*) from tREaltyTrac group by city
```

Comment: the inserts run with 1 second delays each, so the times would be different so you could tell that the oldest ones were the ones that were deleted

Comment: Nice!  In other less-capable SQL engines you might be well advise to make a temporary table for what apparently SQL Server handles well as a nested select (and unfortunately not all engines yet support the sql'03 standard "row_number() over(partition", sigh).

Comment: +1 for using the ROW_NUMBER() ranking function! I was working on two CTE's using the same approach, but you beat me to the punch :-)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should take care of it for you, but deleting records automatically isn't a great idea. You'd be better off using an active flag.

```
DECLARE @CityName VARCHAR(30)
DECLARE CitiesOver10 CURSOR FOR select city from tREaltyTrac group by city having count(city)>10 

OPEN CitiesOver10
FETCH NEXT FROM CitiesOver10 INTO @CityName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM 
            dbo.tREaltyTrac 
        WHERE 
            ID NOT IN (SELECT TOP 10 ID FROM dbo.tREaltyTrac WHERE city = @CityName ORDER BY Creation DESC)
            AND City = @CityName

        FETCH NEXT FROM CitiesOver10 INTO @CityName
    END

CLOSE CitiesOver10
DEALLOCATE CitiesOver10
```

Comment: -1 - avoid CURSORS like the plague! There are smarter ways to do this.

Comment: cursor loops are very slow, there are usually ways to use a single statement, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't delete records out of a database.
this isn't 100% perfect and i'm sure there are better ways to do it, but here ya go.

```
declare @cities (CityName nvarchar(50), ID int identity(1,1))
declare @returns (CityName nvarchar(50), Blah nvarchar(50))
declare @cityname nvarchar(50)
declare @count int
declare @i int


insert into @cities (CityName)
select distinct CityName
from tblCities

select @count = count(*) from @cities
set @i=1

while (@i<=@count)
begin

    select @cityname = CityName from @cities where ID=@i

    select top 10 *
    from tblCities
    where CityName=@cityname
    order by Creation desc

    set @i=@i+1
end
```

Comment: looping is very slow, there are ways to do this in a single statement, see my answer

Comment: yeah, i figured there was a better way to do it, i just couldn't think of it at the time.  that's why i made it a part of my comment.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't got time to write out the actual code right now, but how about something like this.... (assumes PHP)

1. Order your initial query - add **creation DESC**
2. Loop through results, and get the creation date of the 10th result
3. Run another query that deletes everything less than the creation value for the 10th result? - i.e. **DELETE WHERE Creation < $creationDateOfTenthResult**

Hope that makes sense...

Comment: Another possible solution... instead of using the date, have a unique ID field, and then your delete query could be DELETE WHERE uniqueID < $uniqueIDOfTenthResult.

Comment: PHP? I hope you don't fetch all the rows and loop through them in PHP and then delete from there.  looping is very slow, there are ways to do this in a single SQL statement, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

I would select the top ten, throw them in a temp table, delete the original and populate it with the temp table.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your version of sql. Something similar to this might work

SELECT r.City, b.*
 FROM tREaltyTrac r
 join tREaltyTrac b on b.Id in
 ( select top 10 Id from tREaltyTrac where Id = r.Id order by Id Desc )
 group by r.City